# Expected value of $h(X)$. When can the order of $E$ and $h$ be inverted?

Tags: expected-value

This doubt arose when dealing with the typical exercise of calculating the expected grade of a multiple-choice exam answered at random (where each right answer is given $p_1$ points and each wrong answer gets $-p_2$ points).

Let $X \sim \mathrm{Bi}(n,p)$, and consider $h(x)=p_1x -p_2(n-x)= (p_1-np_2)+(p_1+p_2)x$.

In this example, the following equality holds:

$E[h(X)]=h(E[X])$.

My question is: Is this equality always true, for any random variable $X$ and any function $h$? If not, what are some sufficient conditions for it?

For instance: Do the facts of $X$ being a discrete one-dimensional r.v. with finite expected value and $h$ being a linear (i.e., affine) function always imply $E[h(X)]=h(E[X])$?

Comment: $E[h(X)] =h(E[X])$ for affine functions: $h(x) = ax+b$, not for any others.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In real analysis and probability theory there is an elegant result called [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). What this says is that for any random variable $X$ and a convex function $h$ we have

$$h\left(\mathbb{E} [X]\right) \leq \mathbb{E} \left[ h(X) \right]$$

and the inequality is reversed if $h$ is concave, i.e.

$$h\left(\mathbb{E} [X]\right) \geq \mathbb{E} \left[ h(X) \right]$$

Your question, when do we have $h\left(\mathbb{E} [X]\right) = \mathbb{E} \left[ h(X) \right]$, can then be answered by considering functions that are both concave and convex **at the same time**. As pointed out, affine functions clearly meet this requirement, since they are the only concave and convex functions everywhere at the same time.

Comment: I did not know about this property. Thank you! I'll wait for more answers, just in case, but your answer seems satisfying enough to me.

Comment: But most functions are neither convex nor concave over $\mathcal R$. Are there functions that are neither affine, nor convex or concave over $\mathcal R$, for which $h\left(\mathbb{E} [X]\right) = \mathbb{E} \left[ h(X) \right]$ holds?

Comment: @Dilip It's important to be clear about the quantifiers: when $X$ is fixed, the answer is yes; but when $X$ is allowed to vary over all random variables, the answer is no.